# Android upload removes bytes

Tags: android, file, video, upload

I'm trying to upload a video from my android phone (Samsung Galaxy s2) with version 4.1.2.

I have configured an apache server which hosts the uploaded video. My problem is the following : everytime I upload a video from my phone, I have a corrupted file. The file on the server has a few bytes less than the phone's file. It does not come from the server as I've made some tests using an html form and everything went well. So I guess, it's coming from my code but I just can't figure where. Can somebody help me please, I've spent days on it.

This is my code : 
@Override
    public boolean uploadFile() {

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = mMedia.getLocalPath();
    String urlServer = UploadConf.UPLOAD_SERVER;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize, totalBytesRead;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = UploadConf.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;

    try {
        File file = new File(pathToOurFile);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MediaUploader upload"  + file.getName() + " => "  +  file.getPath());

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("mediaTitle", file.getName());

        URL url = new URL(urlServer + getFormattedParams(params));
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "URL => " + urlServer + getFormattedParams(params));
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(UploadConf.CHUNK_SIZE);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mediaFile\"" + lineEnd + lineEnd + file.getName() + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_file\";filename=\"" + file.getName());
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        totalBytesRead = bytesRead;

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {   
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Progress " + totalBytesRead + " Read ");
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            //outputStream.flush();
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        //Get Response  
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();


        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Server Response Code " + serverResponseCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Server Response Message " + serverResponseMessage);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Server Response " + response.toString());

        String result = response.toString();

        if (result == null || result.equals("")) {
            broadcastIntent(mContext.getString(R.string.upload_failed_notification), PRIORITY.ERROR, fileInputStream, outputStream);
        }

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Impossible to parse Json String");
            broadcastIntent(mContext.getString(R.string.upload_failed_notification), PRIORITY.ERROR, fileInputStream, outputStream);
            return false;
        } 

        JSONObject jsonResult = json.getJSONObject(Constants.JSON_RESULT_TAG);

        if (jsonResult == null) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Json result is null ");
            broadcastIntent(mContext.getString(R.string.upload_failed_notification), PRIORITY.ERROR, fileInputStream, outputStream);
            return false;
        }

        JSONArray errors;

        if (jsonResult.has(Constants.JSON_ERRORS_TAG)) {
            if ((errors = jsonResult.getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_ERRORS_TAG)) != null) {

                String notification = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < errors.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject o = errors.getJSONObject(i);

                    notification +=  o.getString(Constants.JSON_ERROR_TAG);
                }
                broadcastIntent(notification, PRIORITY.ERROR, null, null);
                return false;
            }
        }

        mMedia.setSyncState(SyncState.SYNCED.ordinal());
        mMediaManager.updateMedia(mMedia);
        broadcastIntent(mContext.getString(R.string.upload_succeedeed_notification), PRIORITY.INFO, fileInputStream, outputStream);
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        broadcastIntent(mContext.getString(R.string.upload_hostname_error_notification), PRIORITY.ERROR, null, null);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, ex.getStackTrace().toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {    
        broadcastIntent(mContext.getString(R.string.upload_failed_notification), PRIORITY.ERROR, null, null);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Upload failed");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How big is the file, and how many bytes are missing?  Is this strictly a truncation or are bytes missing from the middle?

Comment: I've tried with different sizes going from 200Ko to 14Mo. In general hundreds of bytes are missing. Ex : original file 2213456 bytes, uploaded files 2212889 bytes. Another example. Original  file:  3864 bytes, uploaded file ; 3220 bytes.

Comment: If you're strictly losing bytes from the end then it could be buffered data that isn't being written... but I assume you've run it with `outputStream.flush()` uncommented and it didn't make a difference (though it should really be after the last `writeBytes()` outside the loop, not in every loop).  Something to try: open a buffered file stream on /sdcard and add `write` calls right next to the outputStream calls, then examine the file on disk.  Should tell you if it's a basic problem with I/O or something particular to the network.  How big is MAX_BUFFER_SIZE?

Comment: Yes indeed, I tried with `outputStream.flush()` uncommented. Thanks for your idea. I've openned a BufferedOutputStream and made write calls just after the write calls made on the DataOutputStream. I did only on the loop as other write calls are for creating the http envelopp. What I get on my sd card is a file with EXACTLY the same number of bytes that the totalBytesRead on the loop. So I guess, the problem is a network issue. I keep on digging. MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = CHUNK_SIZE = 1024

Comment: Ok after many try and fail, I found my mistake. A lineend was missing after `outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_file\";filename=\"" + file.getName());`. I've only put one lineend where there shoud have 2 line ends. So the correct code is <br/> <br/> `outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_file\";filename=\"" + file.getName());
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd); outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);`